# Hide html button in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

My webpage have a button that take user to the next section of the page. I want to hide that button in mobile view, but i can not figure out the right css for it.

JSFIDDLE of Code:

https://jsfiddle.net/cgqme8xo/1/#&togetherjs=qTV1soRSqs

Html Code:

```
<section>
<a href="#main" class="scroll-down" address="true" class="text-right hidden-md"></a>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.scroll-down {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
  transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
}

.scroll-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 2px solid #EF4043;
  background-size: 14px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}


.scroll-down:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 8px);
    left: calc(50% - 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    content: "";
    border: 2px solid #EF4043;
    border-width: 0px 0 2px 2px;
}
```

Comment: You're using bootstrap.  You don't need custom css.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use something like:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .scroll-down {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

with the width you need to hide the button

updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/cgqme8xo/2/ just resize the visible area then you will see how it shows / hides the button

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 3 you could use bootstrasp [Responsive Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities) like this:

```
<section >
    <a href="#main" class="scroll-down text-right hidden-xs" address="true"></a>
</section>
```

In Bootstap 4 [Responsive Utilities](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/#content) :

```
<section >
    <a href="#main" class="scroll-down text-right hidden-xs-down" address="true"></a>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes in Bootstrap 4  is available as well...have a look [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/#content)

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
  .scroll-down{
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 461px) {
  .scroll-down{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

How about using `@media screen` ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Bootstrap, you could do it without custom CSS like this:

```
<section class="d-none d-md-block">
  <a href="#main" class="scroll-down" address="true" class="text-right"></a>
</section>
```

Change `d-md-block` to whatever breakpoint and display type best fits your needs. See [the Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) for the available options.

Comment: It will have a display of "none" for everything smaller than the medium breakpoint.  So it will be hidden on mobile, as you requested.  It would probably be better to put the display classes on the `<section>` and not the `<a>`, though. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you wanted. Are you wanting the button to not be visible, but still remain functional?

Comment: I wanted it to get hide in mobile view only. i received the answer bu thank you so much for helping. i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a CSS `@media` query.

The first step is to put a viewport `<meta>` tag in the `<head>` of your HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

Then you use the `@media` query from your CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .scroll-down {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

You can change `max-width: 768px` to however many pixels you want; Basically when the screen width is less than the specified amout, then the CSS inside the query is used, with a higher priority than other CSS.

Try resizing the browser to see if it works.